# Proving a distance function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $k$ be a natural number and $N_k$ be the set of all subsets with $k$ elements. For $X,Y\in N_k$ let $d(X,Y) = |(X\setminus Y) \cup (Y\setminus X)|$ (the number of elements in the union). How do I prove that $d: N_k \times N_k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a distance function on $N_k$?

Comment: well, what are the facts you need to prove about your function? One of these is instantaneous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to show that the four following properties hold for $d$ to be a metric:

1. **If $X,Y \in N_k$ then $d(X,Y) \geq 0$:**

This follows from the fact that the absolute value $|(X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X) | \geq 0$

---

2. **$d(X,Y) = 0$ if and only if $X=Y$:**

($\Rightarrow$) If $X=Y$ then $d(X,Y) = d(X,X) = | X \setminus X \cup X \setminus X| = | \, \emptyset \,  | = 0$.

($\Leftarrow$) If $d(X,Y) = 0$ then $$| (X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X) | = 0 \Rightarrow |X \setminus Y| = | Y \setminus X| = 0 \, \, \,\text{    (why is this true??)}$$ So there does not exist $x \in X$ such that $x \notin Y$ or $y \in Y$ such that $ y \notin X$. So $X = Y$

---

3. **if $X, Y \in N_k$ then $d(X,Y)=d(Y,X)$ :**

Let $X,Y \in N_k$. Then $$d(X,Y) = |(X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)| = | (Y \setminus X) \cup (X \setminus Y)| = d(Y,X)$$

---

4. **if $X,Y,Z \in N_k$ then $d(X,Y) \leq d(X,Z) + d(Z,Y)$:**

Here, it is (extremely) helpful to draw a venn diagram and do some colouring in to convince yourself!

We have $$X \setminus Y = ((Z \cap X) \setminus Y) \cup (X \setminus (Z \cup Y)) \subseteq (Z \setminus Y) \cup (X \setminus Z) $$
and $$ Y \setminus X = ((Z \cap Y) \setminus X) \cup (Y \setminus (Z \cup X)) \subseteq (Z \setminus X) \cup (Y \setminus Z) $$
So $( X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X) \subseteq (X \setminus Z) \cup (Z \setminus X) \cup (Z \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus Z) $ which gives us $ |(X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)| \leq | (X\setminus Z) \cup (Z \setminus X) \cup (Z \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus Z)|$

Then 
\begin{align}
d(X,Z) + d(Z,Y)  & = |(X \setminus Z) \cup (Z \setminus X)| + |(Z \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus Z)|\\  & \geq |(X \setminus Z) \cup (Z \setminus X) \cup (Z \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus Z)|\\ & \geq |(X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)|\\ & = d(X,Y)
\end{align}

Comment: This was very clear. Thank you.

Comment: Please note the innermost operation on sets is subtraction (formally: relative complement), not any kind of division; as such, it is usually denoted with the $\setminus$ operator, encoded with the LaTeX `\setminus` symbol and not with a forward slash $/$.

Comment: @CiaPan thankyou; fixed now